Python: re.match object couldn't use in for loop?
i am a new person for python.
today i have try to caupture a  5 invoice nubmers from 5 text with rex. when i use normal write without loop, it works well
every text a very long text with character , number and spelical signal like \n and so on.
code as bellow:
import re
text1=*****
text2=*****
text3=*****
Invoicenumber = r"(\d+)"
Invoicenumber1= (re.search(Invoicenumber, text1)).group()
Invoicenumber2= (re.search(Invoicenumber, text2)).group()
Invoicenumber3= (re.search(Invoicenumber, text3)).group()
print(Invoicenumber1)
print(Invoicenumber2)
print(Invoicenumber3)

the result is nice and i get the string value
24312000000363021014
24312000000268922839
24317000001097668951

i consider to use loop to make it easy and could use for easy
import re
text1=*****
text2=*****
text3=*****
textsub = [text1,text2,text3]
Invoicenumber = r"(\d+)"

for text in textsub:
        Invoicenumber= (re.search(Invoicenumber, text)).group()
        print(Invoicenumber)

output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\VSproject\xmlconvert\pdfreadtestv1.2.py", line 85, in <module>
    Invoicenumber= (re.search(Invoicenumber, text)).group()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

it make me confued by it coudn't write in for loop? Does caseud by list??? how would i fix it?
Thanks

You reused the Invoicenumber name.

i guest it may casued by reuse invoicenumber, but how to fix if i still want to use for loop? thanks

Hi , Mate. Thanks for you tips, i have note what i wrong

fixed.
import re
text1=*****
text2=*****
text3=*****
textsub = [text1,text2,text3]
Invoicenumbercapture = r"(\d+)"


for text in textsub:
       print((re.search(Invoicenumbercapture, text)).group())

